# Reference for a whole section

Tags: thesis

I want to reference a whole section named TLS 1.2. To not reference every paragraph with the same source, at the beginning of the section I wrote the following "The source used for this section is the RFC 5246 standard document [3] which specifies the TLS version 1.2.".

Is this enough, or is it a must that every paragraph must be referenced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear and complete, so should be fine, subject to the advice of your advisor (for a thesis).

The exception would be if you need to make specific something you write and how it relates to a specific paragraph. Even then, you could cite the entire section and cite again any quotes you need from the document.

But, check with your advisor.

---

The dual purpose of citation is to avoid plagiarism, giving proper credit for ideas, and to continue a chain of evidence.

Comment: I have a similar issue: I need to cite a section (which is about 4 pages long) where I describe a literature article. Can I insert the citation as follows?
``` 
\subsection{title}
The present article [1] reviews the methodology used by...
```
Should the figures be cited individually or is quotation as indicated above sufficient?